# How to disable some NavigationView transition animation?

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

I want to disable transition animation for some of NavigationLink, how do I disable this?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                // ok
                NavigationLink(destination: View2(), label: {Text("Go to view 2")})
                
                Text("Hello")
                
                // I want to disable the transition animation for this navigation link
                NavigationLink(destination: View3(), label: {Text("Go to view 3")})
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
init() {
  UINavigationBar.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
}
```

this should disable your navigationbar animations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33779954)

Comment: allright, I'll edit it to give a proper answer instead.